# iPhone iOS 12.2: music star ratings aren’t saved

Tags: iphone, ios, music.app

I’ve had this problem for a while, possibly since the start of iOS 12.

I have **Show Star Ratings** switches on and can access the star rating for songs in the Music app. I select **Rate Song...** from the action sheet, tap a star rating in the alert view, then tap the **Done** button. However the rating is not saved: if I open up the rating alert view again, it’s back to 0 stars.

This is happening both for music I’ve purchased from iTunes and other music I own.

Has anyone else experienced this? How can I fix it?

Comment: I noticed that when I've done this on my iPhone, and then opened the Rate Song... dialog again, right afterwards it too showed 0 stars; however when I looked at the song in iTunes on my Mac it showed the appropriate rating. When I returned to the iOS dialog it was correct as well. So I think it's working. it's just taking a bit for the interface to catch up.

Comment: @sdmeyers oh wow, looks like that's it! If you put your comment up as an answer I'll accept it and award you the bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that when I've done this on my iPhone, and then opened the Rate Song... dialog again, right afterwards it too showed 0 stars; however when I looked at the song in iTunes on my Mac it showed the appropriate rating. When I returned to the iOS dialog it was correct as well. So I think it's working. it's just taking a bit for the interface to catch up.

Answer (score 0):

This works well..

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250493181

1. active internet
2. make a change to your star rating and press Done
3. push the Radio button - this obviously checks in with iCloud
4. go back to the star rating. it should now have the new setting.